# Using part of logo in creative concepts

Tags: logo, branding, identity

I am requesting feedback regarding the use of the letter "r" from the logo with other images and text to create and overarching theme/identity for the brand. Which of the following options (A, B or C) is a better approach? Thanks!

[image]

Original question:
I designed a logotype for a client's business containing a stylized letter "R". Is it a good idea to use just the stylized "R" from the logotype to develop creative theme/concepts for the brand?

Comment: I do not think so.

Comment: Please see our [criteria for requests similar to this](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/682/23061). I think you can have a good question here if you clarify exactly what you mean by this sentence, perhaps with some example

Comment: @zach, please note updated question and example provided. Thanks for your response!

Comment: Personally I don't care for the logo. I can't tell solely based on it if it's "care" or "case" (based solely on the shapes I'd guess "case"). As such I wouldn't use the stylized R as is at all

Comment: Thanks @zach. The logo is still being tweaked and while logo was not in  question,  I do appreciate the feedback. When you say "I wouldn't use the stylized R as is at all", do you mean in the logo or Option A and B. Please clarify.

Comment: Whether or not I'd use any of these variants depends on the stylized R. Like I said, if it is as is I'd not use it at all

Comment: While I like the concept, it fails legibility-wise. I'd reconsider.

Comment: So the logo itself as it is in blue is not part of the discussion? You wonder if extracting it and using elsewhere is a good / decent / acceptable / phenomenal idea?

Comment: @Benteh Yes, the second part of your question is the feedback I seek..that is the viability of taking such approach. Logo was not part of discussion. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the logo itself is not up for discussion, I will say yes, you can use the r on its own.

**I think example #3 is the best one.**

- 1 gets a little convoluted.
- 2 is rather boring and generic.

I would also like to point out that 2 and 3 have "Lift" higher up and that works well. Lift - float - ascend etc., it emphasises the balloons (presumably) upwards motion, the direction you want your spirits to go :)

Yes; I think you can use the r, but do it with care. The reason I do not think it works well in #1 is partly because the context is missing a little... if the logo had been closer to the balloon/text, possibly in white-on-blue it would not look quite so bizarre jammed into the text like that. But to me it is a little "forced", and unnecessarily so.

It is a possibility that people will not instantly "get it", but I for one thinks that is not always a bad thing. A little intrigue, oddity makes for curious onlooker.

3 works best for me as it is a "freestanding" use of the r. It will then, eventually become an element of identity in itself independent of the logo, but that is in fact perfectly fine. I say go for it. Make the world a little more quirky.

Comment: Thank you! The idea was to take the r further and make it part of the identity. Switching images with it to support copy as and when needed. I see it as having legs. I was just wondering if it is a good approach or a complete "no no" from a branding best practices stand point. Your comments are very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are tasteful ways to do so, especially if the "R" is the first letter of the company name. But even if it's not, I can imagine scenarios where using it as a secondary design element would work. You could even use the outline of the "R" as negative space, something like this:

[image]

Comment: Appreciate your feed back! Please see updated question with supporting image. Thanks!